# is there a way to debug and know whether my layout.xml file is called or not (or) rather is the problem is in my template?

Tags: magento-1.8, layout

My controller works fine
but when i am including layout (i.e loadLayout and renderLayout())
magento displays a blank page with default layout

Is there a way to know which all Layout.xml file's have been called or specifically if my Layout is called  or not

and if it is called then why isn't my template being displayed....
where does the Problem exist
Is there any way or tool to find that out Since every time when i get such problems , i cannot keep posting questions to figure the answer out..

Comment: can you post your layout.xml ?

Comment: The easiest way to test if the layout is loaded is to enable developer mode and make the layout file invalid. If you see an error on the screen then the layout file is loaded.

Comment: @Marius looks like a valid answer. Why not to post it? ;-)

Comment: Hi @Marius, please post your comment as answer along with a link of any tutorial that explains enabling developer mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to test if the layout is loaded is to enable developer mode and make the layout file invalid. If you see an error on the screen then the layout file is loaded.
To enable developer mode add this to the `httpd.conf` of your apache (or corresponding file for other servers), or in the `.htaccess` file. Just remember not to move it on the live server:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1
```

If you don't have access to these files you can just temporarily change this code in index.php

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

to

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//}
```

Again, remember not to leave it like this on the live server.