# error while enabling developer mode

Tags: magento-1.8, error, development, developer-mode

When i enable developer mode, 
the magento doesnot work and displays this error instead

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 88: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: global line 34 and config  in D:\Softwares\xamp_new\htdocs\bhupenShop\lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php on line 513
#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', 'D:\Softwares\xa...', 513, Array)
#1 D:\Softwares\xamp_new\htdocs\bhupenShop\lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php(513): simplexml_load_string('loadString('loadFile('D:\Softwares\xa...')
#4 D:\Softwares\xamp_new\htdocs\bhupenShop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesConfiguration(Array, Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config))
#5 D:\Softwares\xamp_new\htdocs\bhupenShop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#6 D:\Softwares\xamp_new\htdocs\bhupenShop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#7 D:\Softwares\xamp_new\htdocs\bhupenShop\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 D:\Softwares\xamp_new\htdocs\bhupenShop\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

---Below is my config.xml file----

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pfay_UserForm>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version of module -->
        </Pfay_UserForm>
    </modules>
<!-- settings for frontend pages -->
     <frontend>
            <routers>
                <userform>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Pfay_UserForm</module>
                        <frontName>userform</frontName>
                    </args>
                </userform>
            </routers>

            <layout>
               <updates>
                    <userform>
                         <file>Pfay_UserForm.xml</file>
                     </userform>
                </updates>
            </layout>

    </frontend> 

<!-- settings for backend pages -->
        <!-- router s initially -->
    <admin>
     <routers>
         <userform>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
               <module>Pfay_UserForm</module>
               <frontName>userform</frontName>
            </args>
         </userform>
      </routers>
     </admin>

     <!-- then grid and display settings -->

     <adminhtml>
      <layout>
          <updates>
              <userform>
                  <file>pfay_userform.xml</file>
               </userform>
          </updates>
       </layout>


       <menu>
          <userform translate="title" module="userform">
             <title>My UserForm</title>
             <sort_order>100</sort_order>
             <children>
                 <set_time>
                       <title>Details</title>
                       <action>adminuser/adminhtml_index</action>
                  </set_time>
              </children>
           </userform>
        </menu>



    </adminhtml>



    <!-- declaration of every file inside the module goes here -->
     <global>
        <blocks>
             <userform>
                  <class>Pfay_UserForm_Block</class>
             </userform>
          </blocks>


        <!-- ... -->
        <models>
            <userform>
                 <class>Pfay_UserForm_Model</class>
                 <resourceModel>userform_mysql4</resourceModel>
             </userform>
            <userform_mysql4>
                 <class>Pfay_UserForm_Model_Mysql4</class>
                 <entities>
                     <userform>
                       <table>userform</table>
                     </userform>
                  </entities>
            </userform_mysql4>
        </models>
                <!-- allow the plugin to read and write -->
        <resources>
                <!-- connection to write -->
                <userform_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </userform_write>
                <!-- connection to read -->
               <userform_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
               </userform_read>
        </resources>
         <!-- -/- -->
    <!-- ... -->

        <helpers>
            <userform>
                <class>Pfay_UserForm_Helper</class>
            </userform>
        </helpers>
    </global> 

</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an error in one of your config files. the tag `<global>` is not closed.
Check your latest modules. This may also answer one of your [previous questions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/13661/146) to why isn't your layout file loaded.
It's because the config.xml file was not loaded and as a side effect Magento does not know what is your layout file.

Comment: Hi, my <global> tags are closed properly, shall i post my config.xml file if u would like to have a look, coz i have checked it... (or) what else could be the problem?

Comment: sure. Add it to the question. Also you can use this to validate your xml files. http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: wow, thanks for the xmlvalidation.com site

Comment: @user3151033. This xml looks ok. This means that the issue is in an other one. Validate all the `config.xml` files from your modules. Start with the modules from `community` and `local` codepools.

Comment: eureka.. , there indeed was a config file in my local folder, that didn't have a closing </global> tag. and your  xmlvalidation.com link did a great deal of work, thanks a lot for both, the admin mode is now working and showing error. i'll now work with the error's.